# take values to display in different languages in an android application- Localization

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-activity

In my **android** application's **activities**, I have had to use strings in three different languages so as to choose preferred language at the launch of the app. I have design android **UIs** for different screen sizes using **dimension XML files** in values folder. For instance, using

```
android:textSize="@dimen/normalText"
```

in setting dimensions in the text view

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Login Date    : "
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normalText"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

can i use such an approach in using multiple languages enable situation. I need to choose a language at the launch of the app and load all the UI elements with that language. Whenever the language changes at another launch the app must display relevant language elements in the UI. Is this possible.Please help me with useful code segment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make values folder inside res according to your list of languages like:

```
1. values-es
2. values-ta
3. values-fr
```

and set values of resources on particular language folder and then use below link:

http://android.programmerguru.com/android-localization-at-runtime/

EDIT:

below code is for strings.xml file for all languages:

English language(strings.xml into values-en):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Spanish language(strings.xml into values-es):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

French language(strings.xml into values-fr):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mon Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Bonjour le monde !</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: then how can I choose different languages folder when needed. As dimensions in values folder are they taking normally. Also in this case should I create these folders for all values, values-hdpi , values-ldpi and values-mdpi cases. Thank you.

Comment: OK.how can I define the languages so as the application takes the relevant value.

Comment: there is no need to define.. it will show language which will select from spinner which mentioned on that code..

Comment: but in dimension file the devise can get its screen size and set the relevant value. As like that how can I choose the relevant language.

Comment: you dont need to use dimension file. and you must have to enter values in particular language.

Answer (score 1):

I restart app if user changes language:

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourApplication.getInstance(), StartAcitivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(), 0,  i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, intent);

System.exit(2);
```

But would appretiate if someone offer a more elegant solution.

Comment: No I mean can I use XML file to define strings in several languages and if possible how can I do so. Thanks!